# Not able to calculate the VWAP with 2standard deviation bands. Python kite API

Tags: python

I am not able to calculate the VWAP on 5mins timeframe data using kiteapi. there is a significant difference in lower and upper band values when compared with tradingview data.
I am using free kite api which is kite_trade and it is available on github.

Sample output is attached herewith[image: Output]
Tradingview screenshot :[image]

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from kite_trade import *

# Load API key from file
enctoken = open('C:\Python\Algo\key.txt','r').read()
kite = KiteApp(enctoken=enctoken)


def get_ohlc_data(token, interval):
    """Get historical candle data for a given instrument token and interval."""
    from_datetime = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)  # 3 days data
    to_datetime = datetime.datetime.today()
    data = kite.historical_data(token, from_datetime, to_datetime, interval, continuous=False, oi=False)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = df.set_index('timestamp')
    return df

def get_banknifty_future_token():
    """Get the instrument token for the latest BankNifty expiry future."""
    instrument_tokens = pd.DataFrame(kite.instruments("NFO"))
    banknifty_futures = instrument_tokens.loc[(instrument_tokens['exchange'] == 'NFO') & (instrument_tokens['segment'] == 'NFO-FUT') & (instrument_tokens['name'] == 'BANKNIFTY')]
    if banknifty_futures.empty:
        raise ValueError("BankNifty futures not found.")
    return banknifty_futures.iloc[0]['instrument_token']

def get_banknifty_expiry_date():
    """Get the expiry date for the latest BankNifty future contract."""
    now = datetime.date.today()
    if now.month in [1, 2, 3]:
        expiry_month = 3
    elif now.month in [4, 5, 6]:
        expiry_month = 6
    elif now.month in [7, 8, 9]:
        expiry_month = 9
    else:
        expiry_month = 12
    expiry_date = datetime.date(now.year, expiry_month, 28)
    if now > expiry_date:
        expiry_date = datetime.date(now.year + 1, expiry_month, 28)
    return expiry_date

# Get instrument token for BankNifty futures
try:
    token = get_banknifty_future_token()
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    # Download OHLC data
    bnfut = get_ohlc_data(token, "5minute")
    
    # Calculate VWAP
    bnfut['typical_price'] = (bnfut['high'] + bnfut['low'] + bnfut['close']) / 3
    bnfut['tpv'] = bnfut['typical_price'] * bnfut['volume']
    bnfut['cumulative_tpv'] = bnfut['tpv'].cumsum()
    bnfut['cumulative_volume'] = bnfut['volume'].cumsum()
    bnfut['vwap'] = bnfut['cumulative_tpv'] / bnfut['cumulative_volume']
    
    # Calculate 2 standard deviation bands
    bnfut['stddev'] = bnfut['typical_price'].rolling(window=20).std()
    bnfut['upper_band'] = bnfut['vwap'] + 2 * bnfut['stddev']
    bnfut['lower_band'] = bnfut['vwap'] - 2 * bnfut['stddev']
    
    print(bnfut)
```